# How to animate texture coordinates in javafx

Tags: animation, javafx, uv-mapping, javafx-3d

Is there some kind of animation for liquid surfaces that mimics waves by animating uvcoordinates like in the picture below?
Can this method be recreated in the JavaFX framework?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**animating by replacing textcoordinate values**

[image: animating normals]

Animating by replacing texture coordinate values . In this aproach , an integer property changes its value over time with the help of timeline object . there is a listener that will trigger an update in texture u and v coordinate values every time integer property changes . The result will remap normalmap over time bringing a sense of motion.

As you can see the animation only moves in one direction . even if the normal map is seamless tile texture ; this animation is not . it will be reset every 20 seconds . this aproach need improvements , but it's a good starting point I think.

**This is a single javafx functional javafx app you can try**

normal map file is at [this page](https://3dtextures.me/2018/11/29/water-002/)

App.java

```
public class App extends Application {

    private final float[] uvCoords = {3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3};
    private final IntegerProperty keyCycle = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        camera.setTranslateZ(-8);
        camera.setTranslateY(10);
        camera.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        camera.setRotate(45);
        PointLight pointLight = new PointLight(Color.LIGHTYELLOW);

        pointLight.setTranslateZ(-2.5);
        pointLight.setTranslateY(-1.5);
        pointLight.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);

        pointLight.setQuadraticAttenuation(0.1);
        MeshView meshView = makeMeshView();
        PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial(new Color(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
        material.setSpecularColor(Color.LIGHTYELLOW);
        material.setSpecularPower(512);

        Image image = new Image("normal.jpg");
        material.setBumpMap(image);
        meshView.setMaterial(material);

        makeCycle();

        keyCycle.addListener(e -> {

            float add = keyCycle.getValue() / 30000f;

            TriangleMesh mesh = (TriangleMesh) meshView.getMesh();
            for (int i = 0; i < uvCoords.length; i++) {
                uvCoords[i] += add;

            }
            mesh.getTexCoords().set(0, uvCoords, 0, uvCoords.length);

        });

        Group group3d = new Group(camera, meshView, pointLight);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group3d, 640, 480, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        scene.setFill(Color.PERU);
        stage.setTitle("Animating uv coordinates in javafx");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private MeshView makeMeshView() {
        TriangleMesh mesh = new TriangleMesh();

        MeshView mv = new MeshView(mesh);
        mesh.getPoints().addAll(-3, -3, 0, 3, -3, 0, -3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0);
        mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(uvCoords);
        mesh.getFaces().addAll(0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3);
        return mv;
    }

    private void makeCycle() {

        KeyValue start = new KeyValue(keyCycle, 0, Interpolator.LINEAR);

        KeyValue end = new KeyValue(keyCycle, 24 * 20, Interpolator.LINEAR);
        KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(20), start, end);

        Timeline tm = new Timeline(kf);
        tm.setCycleCount(100);
        tm.play();

    }

}
```

Comment: You can also use animated GIFs as the image for maps in `PhongMaterial`, so by using one for the bump map you can also create such an effect.